# How to remove line in image in order to improve OCR results?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, ocr, python-3.6

I'm trying to create a "captcha resolver" thank to an OCR for that kind of CAPTCHA:

[image: 11.png][image: 59.png] [image: 69.png]

So basicly, the two digits and line through them.

I want to delete or at least mitigate the line in order to have better result with my OCR.
For the moment, I have something like that :

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

img = Image.open('captcha.png')
img = img.filter(ImageFilter.UnsharpMask(radius=5, percent=150, threshold=5))
img = img.filter(ImageFilter.MedianFilter(size=3))
img.crop((55, 0, 110, 36)).save('captcha-edited.png')
```

Which give me:

[image: 11-edited.png] [image: 59-edited.png][image: 69-edited.png]

So as you can see the result is not conclusive, and the OCR can not read it easier.
Do you have any idea, to help me to remove or mitigate this line?

Comment: Use [neural networks](https://codepen.io/birjolaxew/post/cracking-captchas-with-neural-networks).